# OneSignal Notifications delay

Tags: android, wordpress, rest, ionic-framework, onesignal

I have an ionic 2 app running on android with a wordpress site providing the data. I have notifications working with onesignal. The problem is that the notification arrives before the rest API data is updated. The App can take up to a minute to update. Is there a way to delay the onesignal notification? or speed up the wordpress json data?

Comment: I found in the documentation that there is a send_after field which I am inserting a date with a must use plugin like so `function onesignal_send_notification_filter($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post)
{
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$newTime = date("M d Y H:i:s e+0000",strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."+2 minutes"));
$fields['send_after'] = (string)$newTime;
return $fields;
}`
however this prevents the notification from sending at all, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing. Modified your codes a little and its working fine.

```php
// Send OneSignal Push after some time delay.
add_filter('onesignal_send_notification', 'onesignal_delay_send', 10, 4);
function onesignal_delay_send($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    //delay
    $delay = '+25 minutes';

    //replace it with your timezone. Mine is UTC+05:30
    $timezone = 0530;
    
    $current_time = current_time('M d Y H:i:s e+$timezone');
    $future_time = date( 'M d Y H:i:s e+$timezone', strtotime( $delay, strtotime( $current_time ) ) );
  
    // Schedule the notification to be sent in the future
    $fields['send_after'] = $future_time;
  
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot speed up wp json data that much, there is some room for improvement (speaking in miliseconds) but nothing much.. just takes time.

If you have programming knowledge, I would recommend this:

- overwrite that plugin, remove calls which occur for notification delivery.
- create your own plugin/code which will only UPON wp json data (successful) run the notification delivery code.

I know it's not much help, but ... :)